# i can't login phpmyadmin in ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, linux, cloud, vps

in my linux vps cant login phpmyadmin as a root

> ip/phpmyadmin

enter user name root and password linux root password but i got a error

> #2002 - No such file or directory
> The server is not responding
>   (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

this is the error  i got in ip/phpmyadmin login fail i don't know the root password so how to reset phpmyadmin root password?

```
mysql -u root -p
```

i try this code in putty terminal but i try linux root password can't enter need a help how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fix this

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

this code will install mysql server with out root password

sudo mysql -u root -p

then enter sudo password   there are no password for mysql root user

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';


FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```